# How Do I Copy Non-Adjacent Cell Values to a Row for a Log Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy three cells, which are non-adjacent (AA9, AA12, and AA15), and paste them on another sheet in a single row, like a log sheet. (A2,B2,C2) I'm using "**getLastRow+1**" to make this happen. Currently, I'm only able to use **getValue** and **setValue** for a single cell (AA9) and after searching for similar examples online, I'm still struggling to make this work.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main")
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log');

// Get the Cell Values from Main Sheet
  var streak = sheet.getRange('AA9').getValue(); 
// Set the Values on Log Sheet
  destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(streak);
```

I'm struggling to understand how to correctly implement what I want. I essentially want to copy the values in AA9, AA12, and AA15, and paste them (or use setValue) in A2,B2, and C2 on the other sheet.

I'm slowly learning and getting a better understanding of everything, and examples from google searches have gotten me far, but this is a headscratcher for me.

- I've tried using Named Ranges, but I didn't understand how to find the last EMPTY row of that named range.
- I've tried creating an Array for those cells, but didn't understand how to use SetValues correctly (got an error about the number of rows not being equal to the data rows, something like that)

```
// THIS DIDN"T WORK
  var results = ['AA9','AA12','AA15'];
  var streak = sheet.getRangeList(results).getRanges().map(range => range.getValues());
 destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValues(streak);
```

- I've also searched google quite a bit, and while the results have helped me script a random number generator (not shown here), I still struggle with more basic tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your latter code example work by using `Range.getValue()` instead of `Range.getValues()`.

To easily append the values to the destination sheet, use `Sheet.appendRow()`, like this:

```js
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
  const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log');
  const data = sheet.getRangeList(['AA9', 'AA12', 'AA15'])
    .getRanges()
    .map(range => range.getValue());
  destSheet.appendRow(data);
```

Comment: Thank you. But...when I change getValues to getValue, now it does something weird. Let me explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [a,,,b,,,c] = sh.getRange("AA9:AA15").getValues().flat();
  dsh.appendRow([a,b,c]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this produces the same strange looping effect that the other suggestion has. Check my response answer please.

Comment: I tested this and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

When I use **getValues**, it works perfectly! But it does throw an error, saying *"Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues."*. But again, it does actually work on my spreadsheet.

When I use **getValue**, it strangely works, and doesn't throw an error, it sets the values appropriately in an appended row, **but then loops back around again and repeatedly sets the value in the first cell again**, albeit one row down (because it just filled the previous row so it moves down). It's so strange. I can see it do it slowly, it sets the values in the row, a split second later it loops back to the first value, but one row down, and sets that value again. But none of the other ones.

If you can visualize this, it'll post 3 numbers, correctly, appended in the row, then one row down it'll post only 1 number, but leave the other two blank.

[Screenshot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KWjH.png)

```
function log_data() {

  const data = sheet.getRangeList(['AA9','AA12','AA15'])
    .getRanges()
    .map(range => range.getValue());
  destSheet.appendRow(data);

  destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(data);
}
```

Comment: The effects you describe are not because of the code you show. Chances are that there is additional code that you run inadvertently, or that you have set up an "on change" trigger without fully understand how it works.

Comment: Please observe that Stack Exchange sites are not "help forums" nor "discussion boards" but **wiki** sites that use the Q&A format. See [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Expected Behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Your post is not an answer. Please add all relevant detail in the question and delete this "answer".

Comment: if you wish to use setValues then you will need a 2d array.